# Duplicate images in search results SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search

Every time I search I get duplicate images in the results. Sometimes it shows up three or four times. If I moved an image to a different folder, the old location of the image shows up in search results with an x as the thumbnail. The "Remove Duplicate Results" box is already checked. Where do I go to sweep the search page and get rid of all the duplicates and old locations? I am a SharePoint Owner and have access to SharePoint Designer, but not to SharePoint Server.

Thank you!

Comment: You'd need an administrator to issue a full crawl to clean those up as that is something done through central administration.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you will need to reset index in order to collapse the duplicated results. When you reset the content index, all search results are immediately removed. After you reset the content index, you must perform a full crawl to create a new content index so that a current results set is available to users.

https://searchunleashed.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/how-remove-duplicate-results-works-in-fast-search-for-sharepoint/